# running a linux program viz command line with php?

Tags: php, linux

Been trying to find an answer for this.  There is a lot of info on running a php script from the linux command line, however, what I would like to know is how to run a linux command line program from a web page via php.

What i'm after is on the fly processing of files from this program:
http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor

Is this possible with php, or would i have to use another language?

Answer (score 1):

You have various options, such as [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) and [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell_exec.php).

Answer (score 1):

The `system` function is what you are looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Answer (score 1):

Both [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) and [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) should be able to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can just use the exec()-command in PHP

For example, I'm using FFMPEG to convert uploaded video's to flv.

You can execute a FFMPEG-command through php like this:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $input -s 320x240 -ar 44100 -r 12 $output");
```